# 'www-data' insufficient rights issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2

i cant seem to make a folder using `exec('mkdir new')` through php using the www-data account...I have done `chmod 775 /var/www` however i still don't have privileges.

Although the foldering is being created, i get the following error

The new folder is actually being created....but the error is still popping up...

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `hello': File exists
```

I have set the owner of `/var/www` to `www-data`, yet the error still persists.

Comment: `chmod 75` won't work, you'll need 755 if www-data is owner or 775 if www-data is only in the group.

Comment: i think the problem is not about permission...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is a file or directory with such name already.
See the error message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `hello': File exists
```

Try this:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir new_file
mkdir new_file
```

You will get the same error. It's not a permission problem. You cannot have two object with the same name in one directory.

Answer (score 0):

May be not a permission problem?

`mkdir -p new`

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the same directory multiple times.  Each time you create it you must delete it before you create it again.  Three solutions:

1. Delete your file.  E.g. `rm -rf hello`
2. If you don't want to delete it and create it again, just check to see if it already exists.  If it does not then run mkdir.
3. Ignore the problem and catch any errors.  The directory will exist with whatever files it had before.